# Jquery mobile not rendering after injecting precompiled handlebars

Tags: jquery-mobile, gulp, handlebars.js

## The Environment

Building an app in PhoneGap and using Handlebars for the templating.  Jquery-mobile is in the mix to provide widgets and some out of the box themes.  The templates are packed with gulp into a build file and rendered onto the page through separate JS files.

## The Route

**The file structure**

```
/-
--|templates/
----|login.hbs/
--|www/
----|js/
------|index.js
------|render/
--------|LoginView.js
```

**The template before packing, login.hbs:**

```
<div class="app" data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Index Page</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Title on Page</h1>
    <button id="login-btn" class="ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left">Login Page</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The file that handles the rendering, LoginView.js**

```
var LoginView = function() {

  this.initialize = function() {
    this.el = $('<div data-role="page"/>');
    this.el.on('click', '#index-btn', this.renderIndex);
  };

  this.render = function() {
    this.el.html(LoginView.template());
    return this;
  };

  this.renderIndex = function() {
    console.log('button click');
    $('body').html(new IndexView().render().el);
  }

  this.initialize();
}
LoginView.template = App.templates.login;
```

**The place where this file is called index.js**

```
var app = {
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent();

    },
    receivedEvent: function() {
        console.log('Received Event!');
        $('body').html(new LoginView().render().el);
        $('body').trigger('create');
    },
    initialize: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.bindEvents();
    }
};
```

## The Question

Is very much like this one about [Jquery not loading on handlebars inject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17243641/jquery-mobile-page-not-rendering-after-injecting-handlebars-template).  But maybe I'm not fully understanding where this method needs to be called.  Currently the Jquery works when the rendering is disabled and simple html is present on the page...  Once the rendering is wired up again:  Blank page.

I've tried several different places so far:

- In the this.render part of LoginView
- In the place where it is now
- tried both 'create' and 'pagecreate'
- used the id of the rendered page instead of body

I've also moved the `<div data-role="page">` around a bit.

Comment: Gajotres who is on SO has a tutorial here if it may help http://www.gajotres.net/using-jquery-mobile-with-handlebars/  -- if not then send him a message to see if he can help

Comment: Thanks @Tasos, I will check that out...  For now I have simplified the stack somewhat and made it work, but I see no reason why this shouldn't work...  Except that I can't get it to...  It would be great to know for the future if this is a viable way to build an app as it is much more organized than the way that I have found to continue with the project I'm working on, gotta make those deadlines.  :)

Comment: Not sure, as there so many frameworks out there i couldn't say which one is the best. Personally and recently i found Googles Polymer to offer an exciting way to build web mobile apps. I developed a few apps in Polymer and i have no complaints. But thats me :)

Comment: This is an ancient string by now, but for what it's worth that is definitely the route I'm going next time.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, Checked it out.  Looks pretty awesome.  Also recently went to a meetup talking about Progressive Web Apps and while I'm not 100 percent on comprehension there, that seems like a very useful route to explore as well.

Comment: cool, its pretty easy to use. plenty on tutorials on how to get started -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eVR2gPS4rpU -- if you dont have a mac or Linux then install Virtualbox on a windows machine and then create a virtual machine (Ubuntu Server) then install Lamp-server to get a web server -- you can then do the rest of the setup from the video and start using Bower to download those Components you wish